# Structure: How to represent a search input, search query, and search results using mobx-state-tree?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I've got an app using `mobx-state-tree` that currently has a few simple stores:

- `Article` represents an article, either sourced through a 3rd party API or written in-house
- `ArticleStore` holds references to articles: `{ articles: {}, isLoading: bool }`

### Simple scenario

This setup works well for simple use-cases, such as fetching articles based on ID. E.g.

1. User navigates to `/article/{articleUri}`
2. `articleStoreInstance.fetch([articleUri])` returns the article in question
3. The ID is picked up in render function, and is rendered using `articleStoreInstance.articles.get(articleUri)`

### Complex scenario

For a more complex scenario, if I wanted to fetch a set of articles based on a complex query, e.g. `{ offset: 100, limit: 100, freeTextQuery: 'Trump' }`, should I then:

1. Have a global `SearchResult` store that simply links to the articles that the user has searched for
2. Instantiate a one-time `SearchResult` store that I pass around for as long as I need it?
3. Keep queries and general UI state out of stores altogether?

I should add that I'd like to keep articles in the stores between page-loads to avoid re-fetching the same content over and over.

Is there a somewhat standardized way of addressing this problem? Any examples to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need might be a `Search` store which keeps track of following information:

- Query params (offset, limit, etc.)
- Query results (results of the last search)
- (Optional) Query state (isLoading)

Then to avoid storing articles in 2 places, the query results should not use `Article` model, but reference to `Article` model. Anytime you query, the actual result will be saved in existing store `ArticleStore`, and `Search` only holds references:

```
import { types, getParent, flow } from 'mobx-state-tree'

const Search = types.model({
    params: // your own params info
    results: types.array(types.reference(Article))
  }).views(self => ({
    get parent() {
      return getParent(self) // get root node to visit ArticleStore
    }
  })).actions(self => ({
    search: flow(function*(params) {
      this.params = params // save query params
      const result = yield searchByQuery(query) // your query here
      this.parent.articleStore.saveArticles(result) // save result to ArticleStore
      this.results = getArticleIds(result) // extract ids here for references
    })
  }))
```

Hope it's what you are looking for.